# DateTime.Hour всегда ли 24?

Tags: c#

Если брать из любого DateTime часы т.е. date.Hour, будут ли они всегда наближаться к 24 или может как-то быть в 12-часовой системе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dateTime.Hour` всегда имеет military(военный) формат. Т.е. 0-23.

Если же хочется получить не-милитари, то нужно это делать уже при переводе из dateTime в строку через метод `ToString("format_text");`

- MMMM - Месяц текстом
- MM - Месяц с предшествующим нулем
- M - просто месяц без нулей
- dd - с ну нулем
- d - без нулей
- yyyy - 4-символьный год
- yy - 2-хсимвольный год
- **HH - 24часовый формат часов(милитари) с предшествующим нулем**
- **H - 24часовый формат(милитари) без предшествующим нуля**
- **hh - 12часовый формат часов с предшествующим нулем**
- **h - 12часовый формат часов без нуля**
- mm - минут с предшествующим нулем
- m - без нуля
- ss - секунды с предшествующим нулем
- s - секунды без предшествующего нуля.

пример:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 2):

[DateTime.Hour Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.datetime.hour?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
Компонент, представляющий час, выраженный как значение от 0 до 23.
Значение Hour свойства всегда выражается в 24-часовом формате.
Чтобы получить строку, которая представляет часы даты и времени, в 12-часовом 
формате, вызовите DateTime.ToString(String) или DateTime.ToString(String, 
IFormatProvider) метод с помощью описателя настраиваемого формата «h».
```