# Перевод формата даты Excel в python datetime формат

Tags: c#, python, datetime

Работаю над задачей перевода формата даты ячейки Excel-я в python datetime формат.
Нашел на английском stackoverflow подходящую реализацию перевода C# формата даты в python datetime формат: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188032/python-datetime-format-like-c-sharp-string-format. Но она также не сработала должным образом.
Примеры Excel форматов:

1. "[$-F800]dddd\,\ mmmm\ dd\,\ yyyy" - соответствует "9 января 1900 г.";
2. "d/mm/yyyy;@" - соответствует "5.01.2015";
3. "[$-FC19]yyyy\,\ dd\ mmmm;@" - соответствует "1900, 24 ноября";

Каким образом перевести формат ячейки типа дата в python datetime формат?
Буду благодарен любой подсказке.

Answer (score 1):

`pip install xlrd`

Возьмем таблицу `report.xlsx` с полем (колонкой, столбцом) `DATETIME` в котором находятся данные в фомате `excel Date`

```py
import pandas as pn
from xlrd.xldate import xldate_as_datetime

df = pn.read_excel('./report.xlsx', header=0,
                    converters={
                    'DATETIME': lambda x: xldate_as_datetime(float(x), 0)
                    }
                  )
```

На выходе получаем DataFrame с полем `DATETIME` в формате `python datetime`

или если брать просто значение отдельной считаной ячейки excel (к примеру `excel_date`):

```py
excel_date = 43951.99999 # к примеру
python_datetime = xldate_as_datetime(float(excel_date), 0)

print(python_datetime.strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S'))
# 30.04.2020 23:59:59
```

Answer (score 0):

если вопрос по шарпу то:

```
var rez = DateTime.ParseExact(inputStr,"паттерн даты", null);
```

паттерн даты можешь сложить по этому ответу: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/946289/186752

---

Если вопрос по python то:

```
rez = datetime.datetime.strptime(inputStr, 'паттерн даты')
```

Comment: Дело в том, что я имею объект ячейка cell с полями value - который является объектом datetime, и number_format - который содержит в себе текстовое представление описанного выше форматов ("[$-F800]dddd\,\ mmmm\ dd\,\ yyyy" ). И имея на входе указанные поля мне нужно вернуть соответствующую строку  - "9 января 1900 г.".

Comment: ну значит после действий из моего ответа переводишь ДатаТайм в стринг используя другой подходящий тебе паттерн. Скорее всего что-то вроде .ToString("d MMMM yyyy г.")